# How to limit the max and min value of number in html text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field which should allow the user to enter numbers,the maximum length should be 2 and the maximum value should be 31 and minimum value should 1
I am able to first 2 conditions but dont know the last 2 conditions

Can anybody help me please?

```
<input type="text"  name = "ccdate" class="form-control" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" >


function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**NOte** I dont want to use HTML5 input type="number"

Comment: guys the fiddle is not working for some reason so I have not posted in question http://jsfiddle.net/rnr45dfz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(Purely Jquery approach):

HTML :

```
<input type="text"  name = "ccdate" class="form-control" maxlength="2">
<div id="div1"></div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$('[name="ccdate"]').keyup(function(){
  if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 31){
    $('#div1').html('value cannot be greater then 31');
    $(this).val('');
  }
  else if(parseInt($(this).val()) < 1)
  {
    $('#div1').html('value cannot be lower then 1');
    $(this).val('');
  }
  else
  { $('#div1').html(''); }
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pft9rwnp/1/)

---

**EDIT :-**(as per questioner comment to check user entered string or number):

```
$('[name="ccdate"]').keyup(function(){
  if(isNaN($(this).val()))
   {
    $('#div1').html('entered string');
    $(this).val('');
   }
  else if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 31){
    $('#div1').html('value cannot be greater then 31');
    $(this).val('');
  }
  else if(parseInt($(this).val()) < 1)
  {
    $('#div1').html('value cannot be lower then 0');
    $(this).val('');
  }
  else
  { $('#div1').html(''); }
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pft9rwnp/2/)

---

**EDIT :-** (Pure Javascript approach)(Just provide a unique `id` to your textbox say `'t1'`)

```
document.getElementById('t1').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
this.value = (parseInt(this.value) < 1 || parseInt(this.value) > 31 || isNaN(this.value)) ? "" : (this.value)
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eopecjfw/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,As you can see I am using pure js to check if user is enering number or string.Your code is totally jquery.So is it ok to mix js with jquery?Can you also provide jquery to check if the user is entering string or number

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.If possible please provide pure js answer

Comment: @SpringLearner..i will definitely try to provide pure js code today i have very bad internet connection i have to test code for pure js answer .. i will try thanks...happy to help you...

Comment: @SpringLearner - Take a look at my answer if you prefer a shorter vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelector("*[name=ccdate]").addEventListener("input", function () {
    var num = +this.value, max = 31, min = 1;          //converts value to a Number
    if(!this.value.length) return false;               //allows empty field
    this.value = isNaN(num) ? min : num > max ? max : num < min  ? min : num;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cha9t3g5/2

Answer (score 1):

Use min and max attributes and if you want user to enter numbers then give input type as number instead of giving it as text...

```
<input type="number" name ="name_u_want_to_give" min="1" max="31" maxlength="2" />
```

Comment: sorry I dont want use input type="number"

Comment: Then you have to use javascript to restrict user to enter non-allowed values..call a function from input element to check the conditions in javascript and return false if conditions fail

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the following code as per your requirements.

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
function minmax(value, min, max) 
{
    if(parseInt(value) < 0 || isNaN(value)) 
        return 0; 
    else if(parseInt(value) > 100) 
        return 100; 
    else return value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="textWeight" id="txtWeight" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value =minmax(this.value, 0, 100)"/>`
```